# How to get the most accurate term in regex?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have an angular app using the mongodb sdk for js. 
I would like to suggest some words on a input field for the user from my words collection, so I did:

```
 getSuggestions(term: string) {
  var regex = new stitch.BSON.BSONRegExp('^' +term , 'i');
  return from(this.words.find({ 'Noun': { $regex: regex } }).execute());
}
```

The problem is that if the user type for example `Bie`, the query returns a lot of documents but the most accurated are the last ones, for example `Bier`, first it returns the bigger words, like `Bieberbach'sche Vermutung`. How can I deal to return the closests documents first?

Comment: So not possible currently to do before you return results from the server. [SERVER-11947](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) discusses addition of a new aggregation operator where part of the spec would be to return "group matches" in which you "could" in theory use the additional match groups to calculate a "ranking" and then sort on that calculated field. Notably this has been recently marked as "desired" for the MongoDB 4.1 release. This should indicate work is in progress to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

A regular-expression is probably not enough to do what you are intending to do here. They can only do what they're meant to do – match a string.  They might be used to give you a *candidate* entry to present to the user, but can't judge or weigh them. You're going to have to devise that logic yourself.